Cannot Upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 LTS
I am new to ubuntu, just wanted to upgrade dedicated server from 20.04 to 22.04. On first run of "do-release-upgrade" all seemed to go fine without errors, but after restart version still was 20.04. When I tried second time, I get no errors, just it terminates. main.log looks like
2024-04-08 21:58:56,672 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.focal', '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d/ubuntu-advantage-upgrades.cfg']'
2024-04-08 21:58:56,672 INFO uname information: 'Linux m17607.contaboserver.net 5.15.0-102-generic #112-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 5 16:50:32 UTC 2024 x86_64'
2024-04-08 21:58:57,115 INFO apt version: '2.4.12'
2024-04-08 21:58:57,116 INFO python version: '3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]'
2024-04-08 21:58:57,119 INFO release-upgrader version '22.04.19' started
2024-04-08 21:58:57,133 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2024-04-08 21:58:57,184 DEBUG setting up environ for non-interactive use
2024-04-08 21:58:57,241 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive' view
2024-04-08 21:58:57,267 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2024-04-08 21:58:57,290 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2024-04-08 21:58:59,650 DEBUG lsb-release: 'focal'
2024-04-08 21:58:59,650 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2024-04-08 21:58:59,650 DEBUG openCache()
2024-04-08 21:58:59,651 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2024-04-08 21:58:59,651 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2024-04-08 21:59:00,340 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-102 with 
2024-04-08 21:59:00,341 DEBUG Comparing 5.4.0-174 with 5.15.0-102
2024-04-08 21:59:00,426 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 87863
2024-04-08 21:59:00,426 DEBUG need_server_mode(): can not find a desktop meta package or key deps, running in server mode
2024-04-08 21:59:00,426 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2024-04-08 21:59:00,426 DEBUG depends: 'apt (>= 2.0.4)'
2024-04-08 21:59:00,426 DEBUG checking: '[('apt', '2.0.4', '>=')]' 
2024-04-08 21:59:00,426 DEBUG depends: 'libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.0.4)'
2024-04-08 21:59:00,426 DEBUG checking: '[('libapt-pkg6.0', '2.0.4', '>=')]' 
2024-04-08 21:59:00,428 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2024-04-08 21:59:01,444 DEBUG openCache()
2024-04-08 21:59:02,129 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-102 with 
2024-04-08 21:59:02,130 DEBUG Comparing 5.4.0-174 with 5.15.0-102
2024-04-08 21:59:02,223 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 87863
2024-04-08 21:59:02,223 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2024-04-08 21:59:02,223 DEBUG quirks: running jammyPostInitialUpdate
2024-04-08 21:59:02,224 DEBUG running Quirks.jammyPostInitialUpdate
2024-04-08 21:59:02,598 DEBUG running Quirks._test_and_fix_missing_nvidia_metapackage
2024-04-08 21:59:02,598 ERROR ubuntu-drivers-common not installed
2024-04-08 21:59:03,429 DEBUG MetaPkgs: 
2024-04-08 21:59:03,633 WARNING no version information for 'base-files' (useCandidate=True)
2024-04-08 21:59:04,680 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'base-files', skipping 
2024-04-08 21:59:04,705 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'crda', skipping 
....
2024-04-08 21:59:05,238 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'proftpd-mod-wrap', skipping 
2024-04-08 21:59:05,241 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'pure-ftpd', skipping 
2024-04-08 21:59:05,241 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'pure-ftpd-common', skipping 
2024-04-08 21:59:05,241 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'pure-ftpd-ldap', skipping 
2024-04-08 21:59:05,241 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'pure-ftpd-mysql', skipping 
2024-04-08 21:59:05,241 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'pure-ftpd-postgresql', skipping 
2024-04-08 21:59:05,281 DEBUG no PkgRecord found for 'python3.8-minimal', skipping 
2024-04-08 21:59:05,365 DEBUG Foreign: apt-plugin-universal-hooks cpanel-analytics cpanel-banners-plugin cpanel-koality-plugin cpanel-letsencrypt-v2 cpanel-plugin-common cpanel-sitejet-plugin ea-apache24 ea-apache24-config ea-apache24-config-runtime ea-apache24-mod-bwlimited ea-apache24-mod-cgid ea-apache24-mod-deflate ea-apache24-mod-expires ea-apache24-mod-headers ea-apache24-mod-mpm-worker ea-apache24-mod-proxy ea-apache24-mod-proxy-fcgi ea-apache24-mod-proxy-http ea-apache24-mod-proxy-wstunnel ea-apache24-mod-security2 ea-apache24-mod-ssl ea-apache24-mod-suexec ea-apache24-mod-suphp ea-apache24-mod-unique-id ea-apache24-tools ea-apr ea-apr-util ea-cpanel-tools ea-documentroot ea-modsec-sdbm-util ea-php-cli ea-php-cli-lsphp ea-php83 ea-php83-pear ea-php83-php-bcmath ea-php83-php-bz2 ea-php83-php-calendar ea-php83-php-cli ea-php83-php-common ea-php83-php-curl ea-php83-php-dba ea-php83-php-devel ea-php83-php-enchant ea-php83-php-exif ea-php83-php-fileinfo ea-php83-php-fpm ea-php83-php-ftp ea-php83-php-gd ea-php83-php-gettext ea-php83-php-gmp ea-php83-php-iconv ea-php83-php-imap ea-php83-php-intl ea-php83-php-ldap ea-php83-php-litespeed ea-php83-php-mbstring ea-php83-php-mysqlnd ea-php83-php-odbc ea-php83-php-opcache ea-php83-php-pdo ea-php83-php-pgsql ea-php83-php-posix ea-php83-php-process ea-php83-php-pspell ea-php83-php-snmp ea-php83-php-soap ea-php83-php-sockets ea-php83-php-tidy ea-php83-php-xml ea-php83-php-zip ea-php83-runtime ea-profiles-cpanel libaps libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient21 mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-client-plugins mysql-community-server mysql-community-server-core mysql-shell plesk-libboost-1.74 plesk-libboost-date-time1.74 plesk-libboost-filesystem1.74 plesk-libboost-program-options1.74 plesk-libboost-regex1.74 plesk-libboost-serialization1.74 plesk-libboost-system1.74 plesk-libboost-thread1.74 plesk-libpoco-1.9.0 plesk-librdbmspp plesk-libstdc++10.3.0 plesk-lmlib plesk-platform-runtime sw-engine wp-toolkit-cpanel
2024-04-08 21:59:05,365 DEBUG Obsolete: ai-bolit alt-curlssl alt-libcurlssl alt-libssh2 alt-libzip alt-openssl-libs alt-php-hyperscan alt-php-internal alt-php-internal-cli alt-php-internal-common alt-php-internal-intl alt-php-internal-mbstring alt-php-internal-mysqlnd alt-php-internal-pdo alt-php-internal-process alt-python311 alt-python311-libs alt-python311-pip-wheel alt-python311-setuptools-wheel alt-sqlite alt-tmpreaper app-version-detector cpanel-3rdparty-bin cpanel-ace-editor cpanel-analog cpanel-angular-chosen cpanel-angular-growl-2 cpanel-angular-minicolors cpanel-angular-ui-bootstrap cpanel-angular-ui-bootstrap-devel cpanel-angular-ui-scroll cpanel-angularjs cpanel-awstats cpanel-bindp cpanel-boost cpanel-boost-program-options cpanel-bootstrap cpanel-bootstrap-devel cpanel-bootstrap-rtl cpanel-bootstrap5 cpanel-chosen cpanel-ckeditor cpanel-common-licenses cpanel-d3-js cpanel-dnspython cpanel-dovecot cpanel-dovecot-xaps cpanel-editarea cpanel-elfinder cpanel-eventsource-polyfill-js cpanel-exim cpanel-fetch-polyfill-js-v3.0 cpanel-fontawesome cpanel-geoipfree-data cpanel-git cpanel-git-gitweb cpanel-git-templates cpanel-handlebarsjs cpanel-jquery cpanel-jquery-minicolors cpanel-jquery-ui cpanel-jsforge cpanel-jstz cpanel-knownproxies-data cpanel-ldns cpanel-libspf2 cpanel-libsrs-alt cpanel-libzip cpanel-libzip-devel cpanel-lodash cpanel-lodash-devel cpanel-mailman cpanel-mariadb-connector cpanel-mariadb-connector-devel cpanel-moment cpanel-ng-cpanel-jupiter-clam-av cpanel-ng-cpanel-jupiter-dynamic-dns cpanel-ng-cpanel-jupiter-manage-calendar-access cpanel-ng-cpanel-jupiter-mysql-manager cpanel-ng-cpanel-jupiter-team-manager cpanel-ng-whm-account-enhancements cpanel-ng-whm-accounts-manager ....... imunify-common imunify-core imunify-notifier imunify-ui imunify-ui-antivirus-cpanel imunify360-venv libicu66 libidn11 libldap-2.4-2 liblua50 liblualib50 libpcre2-posix2 libperl5.30 libsnmp35 libssl1.1 libzip5 linux-image-5.4.0-174-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-174-generic lua50 perl-modules-5.30
2024-04-08 21:59:05,366 DEBUG updateSourcesList()
2024-04-08 21:59:05,375 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList() with mirror_check
2024-04-08 21:59:05,375 DEBUG ['ubuntu-minimal', 'ubuntu-standard']
2024-04-08 21:59:05,375 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-minimal
2024-04-08 21:59:05,377 DEBUG Checking pkg: ubuntu-standard
2024-04-08 21:59:05,379 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy main restricted'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,380 DEBUG entry '# deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy main restricted # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,380 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,381 DEBUG entry '# deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,381 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy universe'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,381 DEBUG entry '# deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy universe # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,381 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates universe'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,382 DEBUG entry '# deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates universe # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,382 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy multiverse'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,383 DEBUG entry '# deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy multiverse # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,383 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,384 DEBUG entry '# deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,384 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,384 DEBUG entry '# deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,384 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,384 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,384 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,384 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,384 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,384 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,385 DEBUG examining: 'deb mirror://httpupdate.cpanel.net/ea4-u20-mirrorlist ./'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,385 DEBUG entry '# deb mirror://httpupdate.cpanel.net/ea4-u20-mirrorlist ./ # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,385 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/wp-toolkit/ ./'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,386 DEBUG entry '# deb https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/wp-toolkit/ ./ # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,386 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/thirdparty/ ./'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,387 DEBUG entry '# deb https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/thirdparty/ ./ # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,387 DEBUG examining: 'deb mirror://httpupdate.cpanel.net/cpanel-plugins-u20-mirrorlist ./'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,387 DEBUG entry '# deb mirror://httpupdate.cpanel.net/cpanel-plugins-u20-mirrorlist ./ # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,387 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,388 DEBUG entry '# deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,388 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,389 DEBUG entry '# deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0 # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,389 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,390 DEBUG entry '# deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,390 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,390 DEBUG entry '# deb-src https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0 # disabled on upgrade to jammy' was disabled (unknown mirror)
2024-04-08 21:59:05,390 ERROR No valid mirror found
2024-04-08 21:59:05,392 DEBUG rewriteSourcesList()
2024-04-08 21:59:05,392 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy main restricted'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,392 DEBUG entry 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy main restricted' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,392 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,393 DEBUG entry 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,393 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy universe'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,394 DEBUG entry 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy universe' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,394 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates universe'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,395 DEBUG entry 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates universe' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,395 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy multiverse'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,395 DEBUG entry 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy multiverse' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,395 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,396 DEBUG entry 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,396 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,397 DEBUG entry 'deb http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,397 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,397 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,397 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,397 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,397 DEBUG examining: 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,397 DEBUG entry 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,397 DEBUG examining: 'deb mirror://httpupdate.cpanel.net/ea4-u20-mirrorlist ./'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,398 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/wp-toolkit/ ./'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,399 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/thirdparty/ ./'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,399 DEBUG examining: 'deb mirror://httpupdate.cpanel.net/cpanel-plugins-u20-mirrorlist ./'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,400 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,401 DEBUG entry 'deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-apt-config' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,401 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,402 DEBUG entry 'deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,402 DEBUG examining: 'deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,402 DEBUG entry 'deb https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-tools' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,402 DEBUG examining: 'deb-src https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0'
2024-04-08 21:59:05,403 DEBUG entry 'deb-src https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ jammy mysql-8.0' is already set to new dist
2024-04-08 21:59:05,438 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=True)
2024-04-08 21:59:06,695 DEBUG openCache()
2024-04-08 21:59:08,551 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-102 with 
2024-04-08 21:59:08,552 DEBUG Comparing 5.4.0-174 with 5.15.0-102
2024-04-08 21:59:08,654 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 87863
2024-04-08 21:59:08,654 DEBUG need_server_mode(): can not find a desktop meta package or key deps, running in server mode
2024-04-08 21:59:08,655 DEBUG quirks: running PreDistUpgradeCache
2024-04-08 21:59:08,655 DEBUG running Quirks.PreDistUpgradeCache
2024-04-08 21:59:10,268 DEBUG Running KeepInstalledSection rules
2024-04-08 21:59:10,696 DEBUG Kernel uname: '5.15.0-102-generic' 
2024-04-08 21:59:10,706 DEBUG nvidiaUpdate()
2024-04-08 21:59:11,504 INFO no old nvidia driver installed, installing no new
2024-04-08 21:59:11,505 DEBUG quirks: running PostDistUpgradeCache
2024-04-08 21:59:11,505 DEBUG running Quirks.PostDistUpgradeCache
2024-04-08 21:59:11,632 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-102 with 
2024-04-08 21:59:11,633 DEBUG Comparing 5.4.0-174 with 5.15.0-102
2024-04-08 21:59:11,793 DEBUG running installTasks
2024-04-08 21:59:12,580 DEBUG About to apply the following changes
2024-04-08 21:59:12,845 DEBUG Keep at same version: accountsservice acl acpid adduser ai-bolit alt-curlssl alt-libcurlssl alt-libssh2 alt-libzip alt-openssl-libs alt-php-hyperscan alt-php-internal alt-php-internal-cli alt-php-internal-common alt-php-internal-intl alt-php-internal-mbstring alt-php-internal-mysqlnd alt-php-internal-pdo alt-php-internal-process alt-python311 alt-python311-libs alt-python311-pip-wheel alt-python311-setuptools-wheel alt-sqlite alt-tmpreaper amd64-microcode app-version-detector apparmor apt apt-file apt-plugin-universal-hooks apt-utils aspell aspell-en at autoconf automake autopoint autotools-dev base-files base-passwd bash bash-completion bind9 bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs bind9-utils binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu brotli bsdextrautils bsdmainutils bsdutils build-essential busybox-initramfs busybox-static bzip2 ca-certificates command-not-found console-setup console-setup-linux coreutils cpanel-3rdparty-bin cpanel-ace-editor .... vim-runtime vim-tiny wamerican wbritish wget whiptail wireless-regdb wp-toolkit-cpanel x11-common x11proto-core-dev x11proto-dev xauth xdg-user-dirs xkb-data xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev xxd xz-utils yajl-tools zip zlib1g zlib1g-dev zstd
2024-04-08 21:59:12,845 DEBUG Upgradable, but held- back: 
2024-04-08 21:59:12,845 DEBUG Remove: 
2024-04-08 21:59:12,845 DEBUG Install: 
2024-04-08 21:59:12,845 DEBUG Upgrade: 
2024-04-08 21:59:12,849 DEBUG apt btrfs snapshots supported: False
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG cache aufs_rw_dir: /tmp/
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG Free space on /: 3716713897984
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG Dir /usr mounted on /
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG Dir /var mounted on /
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG Free space on /boot: 1284366336
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG Dir /var/cache/apt/archives mounted on /
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG Free space on /tmp: 3853803520
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG Dir /home mounted on /
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG Dir /tmp mounted on /tmp
2024-04-08 21:59:12,850 DEBUG fs_free contains: '{'/': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>, '/usr': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>, '/var': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>, '/boot': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfed900>, '/var/cache/apt/archives': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>, '/tmp': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeef50>, '/home': <DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>}'
2024-04-08 21:59:13,121 DEBUG dir '/var/cache/apt/archives' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>' (3716713897984.000000)
2024-04-08 21:59:13,121 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>' (3716713897984.000000)
2024-04-08 21:59:13,121 DEBUG dir '/var' needs '0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>' (3716713897984.000000)
2024-04-08 21:59:13,121 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '52428800' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>' (3716713897984.000000)
2024-04-08 21:59:13,121 DEBUG dir '/boot' needs '69295866.15' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfed900>' (1284366336.000000)
2024-04-08 21:59:13,121 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '5242880' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeef50>' (3853803520.000000)
2024-04-08 21:59:13,121 DEBUG dir '/' needs '10485760' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>' (3716661469184.000000)
2024-04-08 21:59:13,121 DEBUG dir '/tmp' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeef50>' (3848560640.000000)
2024-04-08 21:59:13,121 DEBUG dir '/usr' needs '0.0' of '<DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache.MyCache.checkFreeSpace.<locals>.FreeSpace object at 0x7f63cdfeee60>' (3716650983424.000000)
2024-04-08 21:59:13,122 DEBUG Found writable ESP /dev/sdb1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
2024-04-08 21:59:13,123 DEBUG demoted: 'at g++-9 gcc-10-base libffi7 libfuse2 libstdc++-9-dev ltrace popularity-contest tasksel'
2024-04-08 21:59:13,123 DEBUG found components: {'jammy': {'universe', 'main', 'restricted', 'multiverse'}, 'jammy-updates': {'universe', 'main', 'restricted', 'multiverse'}, 'jammy-security': {'universe', 'main', 'restricted', 'multiverse'}}
2024-04-08 21:59:13,123 DEBUG abort called
2024-04-08 21:59:13,124 ERROR view.abort called
2024-04-08 21:59:13,124 DEBUG openCache()
2024-04-08 21:59:14,979 DEBUG Comparing 5.15.0-102 with 
2024-04-08 21:59:14,981 DEBUG Comparing 5.4.0-174 with 5.15.0-102
2024-04-08 21:59:15,065 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 87863

and apt.log:
Log time: 2024-04-08 21:59:00.424970
Log time: 2024-04-08 21:59:02.214513
Log time: 2024-04-08 21:59:08.635518
  MarkInstall libgpg-error0:amd64 < 1.43-3 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on libgpg-error-l10n:amd64
  MarkInstall linux-image-generic:amd64 < 5.15.0.102.99 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on thermald:amd64
  MarkInstall libc-dev-bin:amd64 < 2.35-0ubuntu3.6 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on libc-devtools:amd64
  MarkInstall e2fsprogs:amd64 < 1.46.5-2ubuntu1.1 @ii mK NPb IPb > FU=0
  ignore old unsatisfied important dependency on e2fsprogs-l10n:amd64
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
Entering ResolveByKeep
None
Log time: 2024-04-08 21:59:15.064714

I have no snapd or screen installed, so that solution did not help me. Thanks in advance for any help.
Edit:
sudo apt update:
Hit:1 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Hit:3 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 https://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:5 https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/wp-toolkit ./ InRelease
Hit:6 https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/thirdparty ./ InRelease
Get:7 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [609 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:9 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,558 kB]
Get:10 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en [297 kB]
Get:11 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [1,695 kB]
Get:12 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted Translation-en [285 kB]
Get:13 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [49.7 kB]
Get:14 http://asi-fs-d.contabo.net/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse Translation-en [12.1 kB]
Get:15 http://httpupdate.cpanel.net/ea4-u20-mirrorlist Mirrorlist
Get:17 http://httpupdate.cpanel.net/cpanel-plugins-u20-mirrorlist Mirrorlist
Hit:18 http://201.159.169.169/cpanelsync/repos/Ubuntu/20/cpanel-plugins ./ InRelease
Hit:16 http://27.50.85.8/cpanelsync/repos/Ubuntu/20/EA4 ./ InRelease
Fetched 4,738 kB in 1s (4,180 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/wp-toolkit/./InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://wp-toolkit.plesk.com/cPanel/Ubuntu-20.04-x86_64/6.3.1/thirdparty/./InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

sudo apt upgrade:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

uname -r:
5.15.0-102-generic

Edit 2:
lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal


@user535733 updated my answer

Your output shows that 1) Your system is properly using 22.04 repositories, 2) No package management errors, 3) Your system is using the correct 22.04 GA kernel. Those suggest a generally successful release-upgrade to 22.04. Please edit your question to elaborate upon "after restart version still was 20.04." What did you see and experience leading you to that conclusion?

@user535733 Not sure if you mean this, but edited post with result of lsb_release -a
